# Refresh a TreeView after having changed items in code-behind

Tags: c#, wpf, treeview, refresh, treeviewitem

I am facing an issue. I created a TreeView in code-behind with different stages of TreeViewItem. I added a ContextMenu with a function "Add an item". When I call this function, I create a new item and I add it to the TreeView. 
The problem is that the view never change. 
I am sure that the new item belong to the list of the TreeViewItem (I looked with debug).
I tried :

```
tree.Items.Refresh
```

and also :

```
this.UpdateLayout();
```

There is my code :

```
public void FillTree(TreeView tree, ObservableCollection<MyObject> nodes)
    {
        tree.Items.Clear();
        TreeViewItem Items= new TreeViewItem();
        Items.Header = "Items";
        TreeViewItem Item1;
        TreeViewItem Item2;
        for (int i = 0; i < nodes.Count; i++)
        {
            Item1 = new TreeViewItem();
            Item1.Header = nodes[i].Name;
            if(nodes[i].list != null && nodes[i].list.Count>0)
            {
                for(int j = 0; j < nodes[i].list.Count; j++)
                {
                     Item2 = new TreeViewItem();
                     Item2.Header = nodes[i].list[j].Name;
                     Item1.Items.Add(Item2);
                 }
             }
             Items.Items.Add(Items1);
        }
        tree.Items.Add(Items);
    }
```

When I click on the button "Validate", it launches this function :

```
public void ActionButtonAddRD(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        FillTree(this.tree, this.nodes);
    }
```

If somebody has an idea to refresh the view it will help me a lot

Thank you by advance

Comment: In WPF, you shouldn't populate the UI controls with data manually, in code-behind. Instead, you should use the powerful data biding and data templating features of WPF.

Comment: The thing is that my tree is too complicated to be binded like this. It contains for example TreeViewItem wiches are not in the data. It is for example : TreeViewItem "Parameters" which contains all items parameter

Comment: @Clement your tree can never be too complicated for bindings and XAML to work. It is lack of knowledge that might be the barrier here instead.

Comment: When you write this.UpdateLayout() - you update the window layour or tree layout? probably the window or user control, try to call tree update layout function,let know if that works (tree.Items.Refresh();tree.UpdateLayout();)

Answer (score 0):

To move the above into a structure that allows for proper data binding, you need to add the following property to your DataContext class:

```
public ObservableCollection<TreeViewItemContext> Collection { get => this._Collection; set { this._Collection = value; this.RaisePropertyChanged(); } }
private ObservableCollection<TreeViewItemContext> _Collection;
```

The `TreeViewItemContext` class would have to look like this to allow to iterate over all items:

```
public class TreeViewItemContext
{
    public ObservableCollection<TreeViewItemContext> Children { get; }
    public MyObject Wrapped { get; }

    /* Other properties etc. go in here. */

    public TreeViewItemContext(MyObject wrapped)
    {
        this.Children = new ObservableCollection<TreeViewItemContext>();
        this.Wrapped = wrapped;
    }

    public IEnumerable<TreeViewItemContext> IterateTree()
    {
        yield return this;
        foreach (var tvic in this.Children)
        {
            foreach (var it in tvic.IterateTree())
            {
                yield return it;
            }
        }
    }
}
```

whilst your XAML code would be as simple as this:

```
<TreeView ItemsSource="{Binding Collection}">
    <TreeView.ItemContainerStyle>
        <Style TargetType="{x:Type TreeViewItem}>
            <Setter Property="Header" Value="{Binding Wrapped.Name}"/>
        </Style>
    </TreeView.ItemContainerStyle>
    <TreeView.Resources>
        <HierarchialDataTemplate ItemsSource="{Binding Children}">
            <!-- Your DataTemplate-Content Goes In Here -->
        </HierarchialDataTemplate>
    </TreeView.Resources>
</TreeView>
```

To then iterate over all items in your TreeView, you would just do `Collection.SelectMany((it) => it.IterateTree())` in your main DataContext object and be done with it.

Doing this then also would allow for you to "just" update the collection by either adding/removing items to/from it or just creating a new one.

the `RaisePropertyChanged` method btw. always is pretty much this:

```
public class AnyClass : INotifyPropertyChanged
{
    public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;
    protected void RaisePropertyChanged([System.Runtime.CompilerServices.CallerMemberName]string callee = "") => this.PropertyChanged?.Invoke(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(callee));
    //...
}
```

All your "update" problems will be gone then.

Answer (score 0):

This issue is easily solved by using the templating functionality of WPF, rather than trying to build the entire U.I. in code.

You already have an observable collection of items, so just set the ItemsSource of the TreeView to that. Inside the Tree, use a HierachicalDataTemplate to specify how each item is displayed.

```
<TreeView.Resources>
    <HierarchicalDataTemplate DataType="{x:Type MyObject}"
                              ItemsSource="{Binding list}">
        <TextBlock Text="{Binding Name}" />
    </HierarchicalDataTemplate>
</TreeView.Resources>
```

Note that list and Name need to be public properties (not fields) of your MyObject class.

This way you can have as many nested levels of items as you require, rather than being limited to only the two sub-levels that your code will support.

If list is also an observable collection, and Name (and any other properties you want to display) implement the INotifyPropertyChanged pattern, then the TreeView display will automatically update after any changes to the MyObject item, with no further processing required.

If you want to go the whole hog and fully implement the MVVM design pattern, then you can find an introduction at my [blog post](http://peregrinesview.uk/wpf-behaviors-part-2-treeview/).